# Suitescript - Is there a way to check to see if the current record has an attachment?

Tags: attachment, record, netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to check to see if the current record has an attachment through Suitescript? I know you can do this through a search. However, I need to check if the current record **on create** has an attachment before saving.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are attaching files using the built-in file attachments sublist, you can call

```
nlapiGetLineItemCount('mediaitem');
```

to see how many files have been attached to a record. This works on both client-side and server-side SuiteScript and for custom and standard NetSuite records.

Comment: May i  to read attachments? example if i'm attached Excel can i read Excel's data.??

Comment: You can get the Internal ID of the attached files using `nlapiGetLineItemValue('mediaitem','mediaitem',1)` and then load that file with `nlapiLoadFile()`. But you can only read file contents using server-side SuiteScript.

Comment: This does not work for me. I attach a test file using the built-in attachment functionality and the console returns "-1" for nlapiGetLineItemCount('mediaitem')

Comment: What record/transaction did you try?

Comment: Are you in edit or view mode on the Vendor Bill? If you're in view mode then you'll get -1 through the Chrome console. I just tried it on a Vendor Bill in edit mode and got the correct value.